# Selenium Webdriver : Suppress IE log info prints on the console

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium

Whenever I launch IE using Selenium WebDriver, it displays a log message on the console which is something like below :

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
2.39.0
Listening on port 5555
```

Is there any way to suppress this log message from not being displayed on the screen?

Thanks,
Sitam

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet provides the logic but untested Java code. You might need to debug a bit.

The documentation is [here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder.html), which you should have a look.

```
InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder ieDriverService = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder().withSilent(true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDriverService.build());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got a workaround: 
`DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
dc.setCapability("silent", true);`. This suppressed IE log info from being displayed in Console. Referrence: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Command-Line_Switches.

Answer (score 0):

After doing R&D for while I got solution for four major browsers.

Chrome = `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.silentOutput", "true");`

Firefox = `System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "null");`

IE =

```
InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder ieDriverService = new InternetExplorerDriverService.Builder().withSilent(true); 
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/main/resources/IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieDriverService.build());`
```

Edge = `System.setProperty(EdgeDriverService.EDGE_DRIVER_LOG_PROPERTY,"null");`

If anyone know other browser properties to suppress console output feel free to share in comments.

Comment: @kembytes try this code if it works for you feel free to upvote.